# what is the best way to include libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create a mobile carousel and the best thing I find is with the jquery mobile library, the problem is that when including it directly in the template it blocks the rendering.

By the way, I am using wordpress.

That is why my query is based on whether there is any good practice to include libraries (in my case jQuery Mobile) without damaging the load / or the pagespeed score for example.

From already thank you very much!!!

Comment: Don't include it all. It's been abandoned for years

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for your answer, I don't understand what you mean by "Don't include everything."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always modify the output of the `<script>` tag by adding a `defer` attribute. This will make your (JS) script non-blocking.

> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Firstly wrap your `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` inside of a `wp_enqueue_scripts` action handler. This is the proper way to register and enqueue scripts and styles [WP Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/).

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jqm_js', 'https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2./jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js', ['jquery'], '1.2.0');

  wp_register_style('jqm_css', 'https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2./jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css', [], '1.2.0');
  wp_enqueue_style('jqm_css',);
}, 10);
```

With the [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) filter, you can modify how the `<script>` tag is being generated. The following snippet will check for each script that is registered and enqueued if the handle is in the `$handles` array. If it is, then it will add a `defer` attribute to the script.

Modify the values in the `$handles` array to add or remove any scripts that you want to defer.

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', function ($tag, $handle, $src) {
  $handles = ['jqm_js'];

  if (in_array($handle, $handles)) {
    $tag = str_replace(' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag);
  }

  return $tag;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Your answer was very useful, I ended up using flickity and it worked very well as you told me! A query why do you use defer="defer" and not just defer?

Comment: That's because if you just do `defer`, then PHP will render it as `defer=""`, which is  valid, but feels more like a side effect, because you didn't specify the empty string in the attribute. If you do `defer="defer"`, then the output will be `defer="defer"`, thus making your code do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good explanation!